# WebRequest Redirect to Interstatial shows blocked by extension instead of the local resource. Not 100% reproducable

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I have an extension that has been working for almost  2 years now with out issue. I havent made any changes in about a year, but recently i started seeing some change in behavior.

I use the Webrequest APi to intercept navigations. During the callback for some websites i need to do some security evaluations async. When this happens I redirect to a local resource (html) as an interstatial page that tells the user what I am doing. Once complete based off the evaualtion the page is redirected where it should be. This is ussually very fast and has worked great for the last 2 years.  Since the latest version of chrome things dont seem to work anymore for all cases.

If i intercept an address bar navigation. everything works as expected. The interstatial pops and everythings great. However. If i click on the same website as a link on a webpage. I get the "Blocked by Extension page". (what you would get if the nav was cancelled). I also noticed that my interstatial is showing up in the web history and if i click on it from my history page everything works. 
It seems as if a bug might have been introduced by google?

Just wondering if anyone has seen this.

Thanks

Comment: I also have a redirector that was working fine for years, now chrome prompts me to confirm redirection every time my extension tries to redirect me

Comment: Without an [MCVE](/help/mcve) the question isn't really suited for StackOverflow. You can report the bug on https://crbug.com but they'll ask for MCVE too (a real extension will do).

Comment: I found the culprate. This issue is that webrequest api can no longer redirect to non- webaccessible content. This is a policy that was documented but not enforced until recently. (change in sept fixed it) The fix is to simply add it to the web_accessible_resources in the manifest.